# A kind of holomorphicity of maps on Hilbert space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, oa.operator-algebras, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional seperable  Hilbert space. Is there an Irreducible involutive sub algebra $D$ of $B(H)$ with the following properties?:

1)For every open set $U\subset H$ and every Frechet differential map
$f:U \to H$ with $Df(x)\in D,\; \forall x\in U$, the mapping $f$ is automatically $C^{\infty}$

2)For every open set $U\subset H$, a uniform limit $f$ of a sequence of  Frechet differential maps $f_n:U \to H$ with $Df_n(x)\in D$ is Frechet differentiable which satisfies $Df(x)\in D,\;\forall x\in U$.

The motivation comes from the concepet of holomorphic functions when we put (the real analogy) $ H=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $D=\left \{\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\ -b&a\end{pmatrix} \mid a,b\in \mathbb{R} \right \}$

Comment: A simple solution would be $D=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In [this book](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Emichor/apbookh-ams.pdf), Thm 7.19 (1) $\Longleftrightarrow$ (9) answers this for $D$ the complex linear bounded maps, but you have to assume that $f$ is Gateaux differentiable with the derivative locally Lipschitz.
2. From Thm 7.17 (7) you can deduce an answer, but you have to adapt the definitions and strengthen the convergence at least at one point.

There is also the book:

- Dineen, Seán
  Complex analysis in locally convex spaces. (English) Zbl 0484.46044
  North-Holland Mathematics Studies, 57. Notas de Matematica (83). Amsterdam - New York - Oxford: North-Holland Publishing Company. XIII, 492 p.

Comment: Thank you  very much for your answer